# MySQL Connect 8 session gives read access violation

Tags: c++14, mysql-connector

I am trying to write a simple C++ program using Connector C++ 8 to connect to MySQL 8.0 running on my laptop. This is Windows 10, and using Visual Studio set to C++ 14. As soon as I try to create a Session, whether through the mysqlx://root@127.0.0.1 call or the mysqlx::Session session(host, port, user, password); call, I get a read access violation in the Utility module in the template

```
_CONSTEXPR20 _Ty exchange(_Ty& _Val, _Other&& _New_val) noexcept(
```

Here is the simple program.

```
// MySQL test.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <mysqlx/xdevapi.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    try {
        std::string user = "newuser";
        std::string password = "new_user";
        std::string host = "localhost";
        unsigned int port = 3306;
     
        // Create a session to connect to the MySQL Server
        //mysqlx::Session session(host, port, user, password);
        const char* url = (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "mysqlx://root@127.0.0.1");
        mysqlx::Session session(url);
        // Use the session to execute SQL statements
        mysqlx::Schema schema = session.getSchema("groceries");
        mysqlx::Table table = schema.getTable("foods");

        // Perform any operations on the table or query data as needed

        // Close the session
        session.close();
    }
    catch (const mysqlx::Error& error) {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << error << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However I can access MYSQL databases from MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE or from a Python program.
The lib file and DLLs are accessed from MYSQL Connector 8.0/lib64 and the code compiles without errors, other than 7 C26439 warnings where functions should be declared noexcept.

I am sure this is a silly error but I don't see it. What do  you suggest?

Other than trying both methods of creating a session, there wasn't much else to try.

Answer (score 0):

I was compiling in Debug mode!  Switching to Release mode and changing the port to 33060 fixed everything.  I guess the only way to get the debug libraries is to build them yourself? Ick!